# Django model register/unregister not working with Profile

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Hi I'm using Userena users system in django website. When I test the project locally everything works fine the problem appears when I deploy it.

```
I have the following model:

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User  
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _  
from userena.models import UserenaBaseProfile  

class Profile(UserenaBaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, verbose_name=_('user'), related_name='my_profile')
```

And the following admin registration

from django.contrib import admin
from accounts import models as acc

```
class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('spoken_languages','favourite_houses','sports')
    fields = ('user','nationality','spoken_languages','smoker','gender','favourite_houses','birthday','school','course','program','sports','housing_status','something_to_say')


admin.site.register(acc.Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

(Please note I've not included all the fields from the original model).

This is working fine under development runserver. But when I deploy it I get an error telling me that Profile is already registered. I tried then adding this line

```
admin.site.unregister(acc.Profile)
```

before it but then the error is Profile is not registered.

I've read somewhere to comment the admin.autodiscover() but this crashes my admin site.

Any idea? and thanks

Comment: Looks like `userena` already registers the profile model for you see [here](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/admin.py#L24)

Comment: Yes that's it thank! I cannot accept your answer as correct because it's a comment!

Comment: I just gave you an upvote so now you have enough reputation so you can [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Looks like userena already registers the profile model for you see [here](https://github.com/bread-and-pepper/django-userena/blob/master/userena/admin.py#L24)"

Actually answered in a comment by [Conrad Kurtz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2221409/conrad-kurtz)